# Typeorm changes field to null when data type doesn't match, how can I prevent this?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity in TypeORM with a Date column like so:

```
@Entity()
export class Payment {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  paymentDate: Date;
  @Column()
  amount: number
}
```

And when I want to save or update a record I send the following payload:

```json
{
amount: 100,
paymentDate: "07/05/2023"
}
```

When I try to save I receive a mySql error that says the paymentDate cannot be null, but the payload is not null and somehow it's setting the value I sent as null. I believe it is because the type is not the same but I'm not completely sure. I want to be able to save Date types by sending a date string since I'm working on an old project and this behavior wasn't happening before, but I upgraded the typeorm version to the most recent one and this started to occur. How can I fix it?
The version I upgraded to is 0.3.17.

I'm also logging the value of the field and is not empty, it's happening when I try to save it